# Generalized linear model (GLM) for panel data?

Tags: generalized-linear-model, references, econometrics, panel-data

I have a panel data and what I need is to use generalized linear model (GLM), but I am confused; that is, I cannot find any related article in which they have used GLM for panel data.

Can you share any article or book where GLM is used for panel data.

Comment: Have a look at genralized linear mixed models (GLMMs). These can model repeated measures / panel data.

Answer (score 1):

Partially answered in comments:

> Have a look at generalized linear mixed models (GLMMs). These can
>   model repeated measures / panel data.

– Frans Rodenburg

[Some posts on this site](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=glmm+panel+).  GLLM's overlap with [multilevel models](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=multilevel+panel+answers%3A1) which is an alternative.

A book that looks useful is [Applied Analysis Economic Social Surveys](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/3642329136). Annette Dobson's [An Introduction to Generalized Linear Models (4th edition)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1138741515) have a chapter on panel data.